# How to convert Virtualbox VM into KVM VM, with latest snapshot included?

Tags: virtualbox, migration, linux-kvm, snapshot, vdi

I have been trying to change my existing Virtualbox VMs (.vdi) into .qcow2 format and run it on KVM.

I have successfully done the conversion (.vdi > .qcow2) but, the converted VM is not in the same state on KVM as it was in Virtualbox.

I read somewhere that it might have something to do with snapshots? I need to merge latest snapshot into the VM.vdi i think? do i? I didn't manage to find anything else on the subject, so...

The question is, how do i convert latest snapshot ie. current state of Virtualbox VM into KVM (.qcow2) VM that are both in the same state?

Comment: but how do i merge snapshot into .vdi? is there a danger of breaking the current system if i do that? and do i merge all snapshots or just the latest?

Comment: See this: https://superuser.com/q/590968/726810 but I don't know if this destroys your current state.

Comment: If i shutdown my server now and take a new snapshot, then convert the new snapshot from .vdi to .qcow2, would this new .qcow2 VM be in the same state the original .vdi VM was at the time of the snapshot taken?